# AWS boto tags returning 0 instances when filtering by tag verified to exist

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I'm using boto to return instances with a cluster_id tag which is a string uuid that uniquely identifies a cluster.

I'm trying to use boto to return the instances with that tag to ensure the cluster has been provisioned and is ready. Thus, when the number of individual instances with the cluster_id tag matches the expected number the cluster is ready and my program can begin the next step of automation.

These instances are in an autoscalling group but im not sure why boto returns 0. I have verified the cluster_id is the same in the program, and the same in aws for each instance. Reservations just returns 0.

Python Code

```
ec2_conn = boto.connect_ec2(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                           aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
reservations = ec2_conn.get_all_instances(filters={"tag:cluster_id":str(cluster_id_tag)})
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
number_of_instances = len(instances)

cluster_id var in the program = 50a5fab0-e166-11e5-9ee9-a45e60e4b9b1
```

ASG tags:

```
ElasticClientNode no                                           Yes
Name              elasticsearch-loading-master-nodes-cluster   Yes
a_or_b            a                                            Yes
cluster_id        50a5fab0-e166-11e5-9ee9-a45e60e4b9b1         Yes
version           1.0                                          Yes
```

Instance Tags

```
 ElasticClientNode         no                                            Show Column
 Name                      elasticsearch-loading-master-nodes-cluster    Hide Column
 a_or_b                    a                                             Show Column
 aws:autoscaling:groupName elasticsearch                                 Show Column
 cluster_id                50a5fab0-e166-11e5-9ee9-a45e60e4b9b1          Show Column
 version                   1.0                                           Show Column
```

Comment: Are you able to query with other tags, for example `Name`?

Comment: It works fine for me. Some other way to test. Print `cluster_id_tag` before `get_all_instances` and see value matches what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

the answer was using connect_to_region not connect_ec2

```
    ec2_conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2",
                                aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                                aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
```